# Python Numpy - Complex Numbers - Is there a function for Polar to Rectangular conversion?

Tags: python, numpy, complex-numbers

Is there a built-in Numpy function to convert a complex number in polar form, a magnitude and an angle (degrees) to one in real and imaginary components?

Clearly I could write my own but it seems like the type of thing for which there is an optimised version included in some module?

More specifically, I have an array of magnitudes and an array of angles:

```
>>> a
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
>>> b
array([120, 121, 120, 120, 121])
```

And what I would like is:

```
>>> c
[(-0.5+0.8660254038j),(-0.515038074+0.8571673007j),(-0.5+0.8660254038j),(-0.5+0.8660254038j),(-0.515038074+0.8571673007j)]
```

Comment: I doubt that there is a built in numpy function, but you could make a function that takes the two arrays and does the conversion

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There isn't a function to do exactly what you want, but there is **[angle](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.angle.html#numpy.angle)**, which does the hardest part.  So, for example, one could define two functions:

```
def P2R(radii, angles):
    return radii * exp(1j*angles)

def R2P(x):
    return abs(x), angle(x)
```

These functions are using radians for input and output, and for degrees, one would need to do the conversion to radians in both functions.

In the numpy [reference](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.math.html#handling-complex-numbers) there's a section on handling complex numbers, and this is where the function you're looking for would be listed (so since they're not there, I don't think they exist within numpy).

Comment: `angle` and `absolute` get you from rectangular to polar, but I don't know of a way to go back.

Comment: @endolith: I edited my answer to include functions to go both directions.  (I didn't included these before because the OP was specifically saying he was looking for something built-in.)

Comment: You can "get back" from polar to rectangular with `Amplitude*exp(1j*Angle_Radians)` - python will print and store this as rectangular complex, and you can use `().real/().imag`.

Comment: FYI, `radii` & `angles` must by Numpy Arrays here.  So the one-liner code looks kind of ugly because of that (saving 3 polars): `a,b,c = np.array([1,2,3])*np.exp(1j*np.array([3.14,1.05,0]))`

Comment: To avoid confuzion, I would change the answer to use the explicitly functions from numpy, e.g. `np.absolute` instead of `abs`, since the latter is also a built-in function.

Comment: @BasSwinckels: surely this is the exact reason for operator overloading, and why numpy uses the `__abs__` method.

Answer (score 5):

There's an error in the previous answer that uses `numpy.vectorize` - cmath.rect is not a module that can be imported.  Numpy also provides the deg2rad function that provides a cleaner piece of code for the angle conversion.   Another version of that code could be:

```
import numpy as np
from cmath import rect

nprect = np.vectorize(rect)

c = nprect(a, np.deg2rad(b))
```

The code uses numpy's vectorize function to return a numpy style version of the standard library's `cmath.rect` function that can be applied element wise across numpy arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I used [cmath](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cmath.html) with [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```
from cmath import rect,pi
from itertools import imap
b = b*pi/180                   # convert from deg to rad
c = [x for x in imap(rect,a,b)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import cmath.rect

nprect = np.vectorize(rect)

c = nprect(a,b*np.pi/180)
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what is going on in your code, to help others.
How does this work exactly?

Answer (score 0):

tom10 answer works fine... you can also expand the Euler's formula to:

```
def P2R(A, phi):
    return A * ( np.cos(phi) + np.sin(phi)*1j )
```